# How to install modsecurity on already configured Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mod-security

I have an already fully configured, functioning Nginx on Ubuntu. I want to add Modsecurity to it. Everything Dr. Google showed me was on how to set them up together, and to compile Nginx with modsecurity. I couldn't find anything on how to integrate modesecurity with an existing Nginx.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since nothing seems to work.

Thanks!